# How to implement ignore error result if output contains something in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible task that sometimes can fail and I want to ignore its failure if, and only if, the output contains a specific text.

Logic sounds like: if result code != 0 and "xxx" in output succeed, else fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any Ansible task can have a `failed_when` option which defines exactly what result makes the task fail. For this to work you first need to register the result of the task which you then can use in the condition in `failed_when`.

> Logic sounds like: if result code != 0 and "xxx" in output succeed, else fail.

That would look something like this

```
- some: task
  register: myResult
  failed_when: myResult.rc == 0 or "xxx" not in myResult.stdout
```

[Docs: Controlling What Defines Failure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure)